# Wordpress custom pages of posts

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, posts

I have the code below which works fine in displaying Posts that are *tagged* with the Page's 'slug'.

The php file is called `pagesofposts.php` as suggested in the wordpress codex documentation.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Page Of Posts
*/

/* This example is for a child theme of Twenty Thirteen: 
*  You'll need to adapt it the HTML structure of your own theme.
*/

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php 
        /* The loop: the_post retrieves the content
         * of the new Page you created to list the posts,
         * e.g., an intro describing the posts shown listed on this Page..
         */
        global $post;
        $slug = get_post( $post )->post_name;

        if ( have_posts() ) :
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

              // Display content of page
              get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
              wp_reset_postdata();

            endwhile;
        endif;

        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $args = array(
            // Change these category SLUGS to suit your use. category_name is comma separated.
            'tag' => $slug, 
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        $list_of_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
        <?php if ( $list_of_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( $list_of_posts->have_posts() ) : $list_of_posts->the_post(); ?>
                <?php // Display content of posts ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

My problem is that the Page title appears as if it is a post as it loses its formatting.

I have included below the default `page.php` file which from my understanding is the default template used by Pages.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages and that other
 * 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>
                        <div class="entry-thumbnail">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentythirteen' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) ); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                    <footer class="entry-meta">
                        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentythirteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
                </article><!-- #post -->

                <?php comments_template(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Could someone please help me combine the two so it acts as a standard page but associated posts are also shown at the bottom.

Comment: you got problem in page title ? both template share same code for title ie header.php

Comment: It's actually in formatting the title, it appears as if it is a post. I have actually just solved it myself. I shall post the code here for others in a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually managed to sort it myself, the code from the two files above, merged into one that works.

The php file is called pagesofposts.php.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Page Of Posts
*/

/* This example is for a child theme of Twenty Thirteen: 
*  You'll need to adapt it the HTML structure of your own theme.
*/

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>
                        <div class="entry-thumbnail">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentythirteen' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) ); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                    <footer class="entry-meta">
                        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentythirteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
                </article><!-- #post -->

<?php

    global $post;
        $slug = get_post( $post )->post_name;

        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $args = array(
            // Change these category SLUGS to suit your use. category_name is comma separated.
            'tag' => $slug, 
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        $list_of_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
        <?php if ( $list_of_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( $list_of_posts->have_posts() ) : $list_of_posts->the_post(); ?>
                <?php // Display content of posts ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```